# ¿Está "Sábete" bien dicho?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales

Estaba buscando textos ejemplos cuando di con [determinada](http://www.blindtextgenerator.com/es) página, que mostraba en una porción de un texto ejemplo de:

> Don Quijote": (...) le dijo: Sábete, Sancho, que no es (...).

"Sábete" resulta muy extraño para mí. Yo usaría "sepa", que supongo que sea el imperativo del verbo saber.

Quiero saber si es correcto usar esa expresión y cuáles serían los [accidentes gramaticales](http://reglasespanol.about.com/od/gramaticanivelprincipiante/a/accidentes-gramaticales-del-verbo.htm) de este, y si hay alguna otra forma de expresar esa idea.

Answer (score 5):

"Sabe" es de hecho la forma de [imperativo para "*saber*"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WsvRvUO)<sup>1</sup> para segunda persona singular. "Sepa" es la tercera persona, que en imperativo solo se usa para el ustedeo. Desde luego lo normal habría sido usar en su lugar, por ejemplo,

> **Has de saber**, Sancho, que no es (...)

Ese `te` resulta muy raro ahí. Yo podría decir

> Aprénde**te** las capitales de estos países
>
> No consigo aprender**me** las capitales de estos países

El uso del pronombre depende de si el verbo es transitivo, pronominal, estamos ante una acción reflexiva, etc. "Saber" puede funcionar como transitivo e intransitivo, pero yo la verdad no entiendo el uso de ese pronombre ahí, aún sin saber el resto de la frase. Ojo, no es que este mal, porque yo podría decir

> Estúdia**te** las capitales de estos países y sábe**te**las de memoria para el día del examen, que es muy importante.

Pero claro, eso es el Quijote, que es castellano antiguo, y no hablan exactamente como hablamos hoy día.

---

<sup>1. Si el enlace no se muestra bien, dale al botón azul de "conjugar" y mira la forma del imperativo al final de la página</sup>

Comment: ¿Tú dirías «No consigo aprendeme» o «aprendete»?  Suena medio asturiano jajaja (seguramente querías decir «aprenderme» y «aprenderte» o «apréndete»)

Comment: Y tenía un "estudiate" también... eso me pasa por estar más pendiente de poner los asterisquitos del formato que los acentos (que me lleva cuatro golpes de tecla por cada uno con este teclado) o del contenido. _Gasias po_ el aviso... ;-)

Comment: El verbo *saber*, aunque no lo diga el DRAE, se usa a veces como pronominal. Hoy día, sobre todo, con el sentido de saber de memoria (ej. *no me sé los nombres de los hijos de mis amigos*). Tal vez hace unos siglos el uso pronominal estaba más extendido.

Comment: Por otro lado, no olvidemos que Don Quijote usa muchas veces expresiones y formas medievales. Ahí sí que ya nos metemos en diferencias sustanciales con el castellano actual.

Answer (score 4):

La forma *sábete* puede que nos suene ahora mal, y que la sustituyamos por *has de saber* o *que sepas*, pero hubo un tiempo en que era la forma acostumbrada e incluso se puede encontrar en textos recientes. Buscando en el CORDE encuentro 315 casos en 150 documentos en textos que van desde el siglo XV hasta la actualidad. Te pongo algunos ejemplos:

> *¡Oh vieja Celestina! ¿Vas alegre? Sábete que la meitad está hecha cuando tienen buen principio las cosas.*
>
> Fernando de Rojas, "La Celestina. Tragicomedia de Calisto y Melibea", c1499-1502 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *—Sábete de cierto que tu hermano y mi señor marido, el rey, será aquí muy presto, y, porque no tome ningún pesar ni sospecha de tu prisión, te quiero soltar de ella con que calles tu maldad, que yo te prometo, a fe de quien soy, de tener celada ni injuria.*
>
> Juan de Timoneda, "El Patrañuelo", 1566 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Dime con quién andas, hijo, y diréte quién eres; cada oveja con su pareja; sábete, hijo, que de la mano a la boca se pierde la sopa.*
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "La vida del Buscón llamado don Pablos", 1626 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *"¿Te falta la salud? Pues, caballero,
>
>   De todo tu dinero,
>
>   Nobleza, juventud y poderío
>
>   Sábete que me río:
>
>   Trata de recobrarla, pues perdida,
>
>   ¿De qué sirven los bienes de esta vida?"*
>
> Félix María de Samaniego, "Fábulas", 1781-1784 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *—Pues sábete que Lucía quiere desde que estaba chiquita a un hermano de Braulio que pronto vendrá; y no te quepa duda, porque Tránsito me lo ha contado.*
>
> Jorge Isaacs, "María", 1867 (Colombia).
>
> ---
>
> *—Sábete de una vez por todas que pienso pagarme lo que le hicieron a Odilón, sea quien sea el que lo mató.*
>
> Juan Rulfo, "El llano en llamas", 1953 (México).

El CREA tan solo me encuentra 4 casos en 4 documentos, pongo el más reciente como ejemplo:

> *—¡Engendro fallido! Del demonio será, y sábete que no es el primero, tú no sabes nada, chata. ¡Nada!*
>
> Eladia González, "Quién como Dios", 1999 (México).

Como ya ha apuntado Diego, *sabe* es el imperativo del verbo *saber* para la segunda persona del singular. Suena raro por infrecuente, la primera vez que vi escrito este tiempo fue en la novela *[Shogun](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogun_(novela))*. Si no recuerdo mal, en la traducción al español se usa así:

> —[...] pero sabe que esta noche soy tuya.

Por último, otras formas de expresar esta misma idea hoy día serían:

> Sábete, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
>   Que sepas, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
>   Has de saber, Sancho, que no es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.
>   ¿Sabes qué, Sancho? No es un hombre más que otro si no hace más que otro.

Comment: Tan documentado (como siempre). Eres imbatible con el CORDE y el CREA, yo ahí me mareo.

Comment: @Rodrigo la verdad es que no son herramientas muy intuitivas, pero ya les tengo cogido el vicio. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Si bien estoy de acuerdo con las respuestas anteriores, se me antoja que la pregunta encierra algo más: ¿puede un verbo aparentemente involuntario como “saber” utilizarse en imperativo? He aquí mi respuesta: muchas veces los verbos involuntarios como “dormir”, “soñar”, “ver”, “oír”, etc. adoptan un uso voluntario que permite su uso en imperativo:

- Duérmete, mi niño.
- Sueña cosas lindas.
- Vé qué hermosa que está (aquí sería más apropiado decir “mira”).
- Oye el canto de los pájaros (aquí sería más apropiado decir “escucha”).

Los dos casos en que se me ocurre que puede utilizarse “Sábete” en el español contemporáneo corresponden al “uso voluntario” de las dos primeras acepciones de ese verbo en el DRAE:

1. tr. Tener noticia o conocimiento de algo. *Supimos que se había casado.*
2. tr. Estar instruido en algo. *Sabe química.*

Los ejemplos respectivos serían:

1. Sábete afortunado. (Considérate afortunado, Entérate de que eres un afortunado)
2. Sábete bien la lección. (Apréndete bien la lección, Estudia bien la lección)

Estos dos posibles significados son, a mi entender, los únicos que se aceptarían para “Sábete” en el español moderno, y para diferenciarlos resulta muy útil la sintaxis del pronombre enclítico que acompaña al verbo. En (1), “te” es reflexivo: “Sabe que **tú** eres afortunado”, mientras que en (2) “te” es un dativo ético, asociado a la completitud de la acción, como si dijéramos: “Apréndetela toda”. El uso del “Sábete” de la pregunta, que no existe en el español moderno, tiene la curiosidad de combinar el significado de (1) (“saber” como “enterarse, anoticiarse”) con el dativo ético de (2).